# interactive curve drawing

Tags: c#, c, algorithm, math

I have set of x coordinates x={0,32,64,...256} and y={2,6,4....},i ll plot the graph along x_y axis,then i drag the point 128 to 64 along x axis,now i want left side of the point to be compressed and right side to be enlarged.How can i recalculate the coordinates of the graph in C.
Any help is appreciated. here  is my code...

```
int arr_x[]={32,64,96,128,160,192,224,256};
int arr_y[]={7,12,8,6,14,22,18,24};

int x1=64,x2=128; //drag x2 to x1
int min_val=abs(arr_x[0]-x2);
int idx=0;

 for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if ((abs(arr_x[i] -x2)) < min_val)
            {
                min_val = abs(arr_x[i] - x2);
                idx = i;
            }
        }

 float r;//ratio for compression and enlarge

 if(x2>x1)
 {
     arr_x[idx]=x2;
     r=(float)x2/x1;

         for(int i=0;i<=idx;i++)
         {
         arr_x[i]=arr_x[i]*r;
         }

     for(int i=idx+1;i<8;i++)
     {
         arr_x[i]=arr_x[i]/r;
     }
 }
 else
 {
     arr_x[idx]=x2;
     r=(float)x1/x2;

      for(int i=0;i<=idx;i++)
         {
         arr_x[i]=arr_x[i]*r;
         }

     for(int i=idx+1;i<8;i++)
     {
         arr_x[i]=arr_x[i]/r;
     }
```

Comment: What have you done already? What's your current algorithm?

Comment: @Alastair:please find the code above...

Comment: @Javed: C# for plotting graph and C(dll)to calculate coordinates

Comment: plotting graph in C# Windows form by paintEvent?

Comment: no..using zedgraph...but i dont know how to recalculate the coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two coodinate systems to avoid confusion. One on the screen (S), one on your axes (X).  Both go from {0 ... 256}

You need to calculate screen coordinates when you move one axis point.

Suppose you move the point X0 to position S1.

```
So, if X < X0 the screen coordinate for X is (X * S1/X0)

If X > X0 the screen coordinate for X is  ((256-S1)/(256-X0))*(X-X0)+S1
```

In your example, replace X0 by 128 and S1 by 64.

One example:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

HTH!